# Error React Redux Toolkit: Why I can't change the key value the array object using .findIndex

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm creating a simple todo app using React Redux Toolkit. If user click the checkbox it will change the key value of .isComplete. I used the .findIndex to find the index of the specific task. But the problem is I can't change the key value of the first object of the array, While the rest is working great.

```
const initialState = [
  {
    _id: uuidv4(),
    title: 'Learn React',
    desc: 'Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis.',
    isComplete: false,
    priority: 'Minor',
    created: 'johndoe',
    assigned: 'J Doe',
    dateCreated: new Date(),
    dateDue: new Date(),
  },
  {
    _id: uuidv4(),
    title: 'Learn Node JS',
    desc:
      'Risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. Est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum.\n\nUt lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel.\n\nFacilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque.',
    isComplete: false,
    priority: 'High',
    created: 'johndoe',
    assigned: 'J Doe',
    dateCreated: new Date(),
    dateDue: new Date(),
  },  
];

JS
export const taskSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'tasks',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    completeTodo: (state, action) => {
      const taskIndex = state.findIndex((e) => e._id === action.payload);
      if (taskIndex) {
        state[taskIndex].isComplete = true;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `findIndex` is `-1` if nothing is found and `0` for the first item. Which will be skipped by your `if` since it's a false value.

Correct is probably

```js
      const taskIndex = state.findIndex((e) => e._id === action.payload);
      if (taskIndex !== -1) {
        state[taskIndex].isComplete = true;
      }
```

but you could also do

```js
      const task = state.find((e) => e._id === action.payload);
      if (task) {
        task.isComplete = true;
      }
```

Comment: I forgot about the return value of .findIndex. I'm stupid haha. The .find is the original solution that I'm planning, I just want to explore the .findIndex. Thank you so much sir for helping me!!!